# How can I install a Canon driver for iP1700?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, canon

I need a driver for my printer so it can work in Ubuntu 14.04. But I couldn't find one in the deafault drivers list that Ubuntu gives. I had already tried these two methods I found:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/CanonPrinters/CanonPixmaIP1700

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1956748&s=bacdd0f41b0ea6797b688cc35a4289d1

but Ubuntu ends deleting the packages because it considers that they are useless. Please I need your help. I am a little new in Ubuntu, so if you come with a solution, please explain me with many details as you can.

Thank you

Comment: What do mean by _Ubuntu deletes the packages_, please explain further?

Comment: I've seen people recommend that you just use the driver for the Canon iP2200.